# Link tag generated on server causes page reload in ember app when clicked

Tags: ember.js

I have one situation in my Ember.js app where JSON for a Highcharts chart is generated by the server. In the chart there are links to pages in the ember app generated for the various labels. The browser behavior on these link is different that links generated from within the Ember app in that the links generated on the server appear to cause a complete page reload (unlike the normal behavior for a ember link). I have tried both absolute and relative paths.

This reminds me of that common, pre-Javascript framework problem where if a DOM fragment where added via AJAX, event listeners would not be properly applied.

Is it possible to create a link server-side that behaves as if it were an Ember generated link? I have flexibility to modify the `<a>` tags the server generates as needed.

Example JSON response from the server looks something like this:

```
{
  pie: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: "<a href=\"/valid-ember-path/{point.id}\">{point.name}</a>: {point.percentage:.1f}%",
      useHTML: true
    }
  }
}
```

Highcharts then renders as a label on a pie chart. The equivalent in the ember template would look like:

```
{{#link-to 'valid-ember-path' obj.id}}{{obj.name}}{{/link-to}}
```

Which, of course, works normally.

Comment: Have you compared the url generated with link-to and your server url? Might be a small difference. Try adding a '#' in front of the url unless you specified location as history for the router. format: "<a href=\"#/valid-ember-path/{point.id}\">{point.name}</a>: {point.percentage:.1f}%",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anchor tag won't work here. Internal links only work with `link-to` and or an `action` because Ember puts an id on them and keeps track of them in memory.

I hate to suggest this as an answer, but I've looked into it and don't see another way. I think you'll need to bind to the click events using jquery.

Here's an example using [`ember-highcharts`](https://github.com/ahmadsoe/ember-highcharts):

Wherever you define your chart data:

```
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: `<a data-chart-path=\"/valid-route\">{point.name}</a>: {point.percentage:.1f}%`,
          useHTML: true
        }
      }
    }
```

Also define an action that you can pass into your highcharts component:

```
  actions: {
    setupAnchors() {
      Ember.$('[data-chart-path]').on('click', (e) => {
        const path = Ember.$(e.target).data('chart-path');
        this.transitionToRoute(path);
      });
    }
  }
```

And in your template where you call the chart component:

```
{{high-charts content=chartData chartOptions=chartOptions theme=theme callback=(action 'setupAnchors')}}
```

Note you will also want to remove the click event bindings when the chart is removed from the DOM.

Comment: That's pretty elegant, actually. I'm going to give it a shot.